# Как работает Ember.run?

Tags: ember.js

Всем привет. Нашел в коде такое

```
Ember.run(null, reject, response.responseJSON);
```

Может кто-нибудь знает, что каждый из параметров в данном случае делает? В доках на офф сайте по этому поводу ничего дельного не нашел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте всё же начнём с документации.

```
  @class run
  @constructor
  @param {Object} [target] target of method to call
  @param {Function|String} method Method to invoke.
    May be a function or a string. If you pass a string
    then it will be looked up on the passed target.
  @param {Object} [args*] Any additional arguments you wish to pass to the method.
  @return {Object} return value from invoking the passed function.
```

Что тут не понятно?